# How can restrict the type of files into Dropzone?

Tags: dropzone.js

I introduced Dropzone library and works well. What I wish to do is restrict only upload images (.jpg, .png)

This is **code HTML:**

```
<div class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="myDrop">
              <div class="dz-default dz-message" data-dz-message="">
                     <span>Click or drag file here</span>
              </div>
</div>
```

This is **code JS:**

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myDrop", { url: "<?php echo $this->serverUrl().str_replace('public','',$this->basePath()) ?>/user/editpatient/<?php echo $this->pacientInfo->id;?>"});
```

I tried to add this code after the first line of code but not work

```
acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
```

Can you help me solve this problem please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "after the first line" but `acceptedFiles` option must go inside the dropzone configuration.

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myDrop", {
    acceptedFiles: "image/*",
    url: "<?php echo $this->serverUrl().str_replace('public','',$this->basePath()) ?>/user/editpatient/<?php echo $this->pacientInfo->id;?>"
});
```

Also point that you shouldn't relay only on this kind of verification, it is better to check files on server side anyway.